# Apache server on CentOS 7 not listening to the IP address assigned

Tags: linux, centos

I have an IP address which is provided by my university to setup a server on CentOS 7 Linux machine. But the IP address of my machine is different from the IP address that I have been given which has a domain name assigned to it. I am very new to networking, please help me how shall I assign this IP address to my machine and setup the server so that I can use it to host my website as well as use it remotely using ftp.

I have Apache server and ftp installed on my machine, I see that the status is active for both.

When I ping the IP address that I have been given I receive no response not even timeout message. I have to use ctrl c to come out of that.

Comment: Is your server configured to use DHCP ?

Comment: Who gave you this IP address? Why does your system have a different address? You need to be specific about every detail.

Comment: @lain: yes it is configured to use DHCP.

Comment: @Michael: This IP address is the LAN network IP address for my machine within the university campus. The it department gave had assigned a domain name along with IP address for our server.

Comment: I'm voting to move this question to [unix.se] since basic networking questions are on-topic there.

Comment: I suggested the steps to assign the server an IP address, but I could be misreading your question. If you give any other details I'll try to give you a more exact answer.

Answer (score 0):

As `root` you need to get the current adapter being used, you can attain this by typing `ifconfig`, you should theoretically only have two things listed

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
          inet addr:XXX.XXX.XXX.X  Bcast:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  Mask:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:219157 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:64295 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:56270371 (53.6 MiB)  TX bytes:27495256 (26.2 MiB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:93800000-93ffffff

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:112 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:112 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:6576 (6.4 KiB)  TX bytes:6576 (6.4 KiB)
```

In this example `eth0` is my adapter
edit:
`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`

```
DEVICE=eth0
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=none
HWADDR=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
IPADDR=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
NETMASK=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
GATEWAY=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
DNS1=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
DNS2=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
DOMAIN='domain.example.net'
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
NAME="System eth0"
USERCTL=no
```

Change that file to the IP address that the was given to you by the university.
Once that file is updated, use `systemctl restart networking` to reset your networking service and update the settings.